# Computing the Kronecker product over a tensor chain

Tags: python, beginner, iteration

I'm working on some Python code and have a few functions which do similar things, and the only way I've found of writing them is quite ugly and not very clear.

In the example below, the goal is to compute the Kronecker product over a tensor chain of length `M`, in which the `m`th tensor is `R` and every other tensor is `J`.

Is there any nice way to rewrite this?

```
def make_rotate_target(m, M, J, R): 
    out = J
    if M == 1:
        return R
    else:
        for i in range(M):
            if i == 0:
                out = J
            else:
                if i + 1 == m:
                    out = np.kron(out, R)
                else:
                    out = np.kron(out, J)
    return out
```

Comment: This title is too generic. Please follow the guidelines: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) is what you need here:

```
from functools import reduce

def make_rotate_target(m, M, J, R):
    input_chain = [J] * M
    input_chain[m - 1] = R
    return reduce(np.kron, input_chain)
```

The `input_chain` list could be replaced with an iterable constructed from `itertools.repeat` and `itertools.chain` to save space.

```
from functools import reduce
from itertools import repeat, chain

def make_rotate_target(m, M, J, R):
    input_chain = chain(repeat(J, m - 1), [R], repeat(J, M - m))
    return reduce(np.kron, input_chain)
```

The computation could be accelerated by exploiting the associative property of the Kronecker product:
$$\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{m-1}\otimes R\otimes\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{M-m} \\
=(\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{m-1})\otimes R\otimes(\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{M-m}) $$
$$\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{a + b}=(\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{a})\otimes(\underbrace{J\otimes J\otimes\cdots\otimes J}_{b})$$

So some intermediate computation results could be reused. I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: A beautiful solution. I knew something like this was possible. I think I'll be using the `reduce` function a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @DanGoldwater FYI, many `numpy` functions (but not `np.kron`) has it own implementation of `reduce` (see [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce)) that supports reduction along an axis of an `ndarray`. You may need that in some cases. BTW, you could upvote my post while accepting it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `M` is non-negative you can make it clear when J and R are returned and remove some of the nested if-else's.

Since `if i+1 ==m` only evaluates as true if `m <= M` you could check that and use different for loops if it's true/false to make things slightly faster but I think that would decrease readability for not much gain

```
def make_rotate_target(m, M, J, R):
    if M == 0:
        return J

    if M == 1:
        return R

    out = J
    for i in range(1, M):
        if i + 1 == m:
            out = np.kron(out, R)
        else:
            out = np.kron(out, J)

    return out
```